# Parsing a Name in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to split a name into three fields. The name in the table is "Last Name", "First Name", "Middle Initial". I have found several articles helping me with what I need for the most part. I have 2/3 of what I need. The issue that I am running in to is that some of the last names have a space in them. For example, "*Van Damme, Jean C*".

I can get the "Last Name" field, and the "Middle Initial" field just fine in my query, but the issue I am running into is the "First Name" field in the query returns both the First Name and Middle Initial.

So my query gives me: *Van Dame* in the "Last Name" field, *Jean C* in the "First Name" field, and *C* in the "Middle Initial" field. I need the "First Name" field to give me just *Jean*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Once you have the last name removed, just search for space in the string.  Anything on the left is then First Name, and right is Middle initial.

Comment: Post your query SQL statement for analysis.

Comment: This is what I have

Left([Name],InStr(1,[Name],",")-1) AS MEMBER_NAME_LAST, IIf([Name] Like "* *,*",Right(Trim([Name]),Len(Trim([Name]))-InStr(InStr(1,[Name]," ")+1,[Name]," ")),Right(Trim([Name]),Len(Trim([Name]))-InStr(1,[Name]," "))) AS MEMBER_NAME_FIRST, IIf([Name] Like "* * *",Right([Name],1)," ") AS MEMBER_NAME_MIDDLE

Answer (score 0):

Might be tough. This is why we normalize tables/ account for data granularity.

You can perform a split again on the firstname part with the middle name, then get the last item of the string array and set that as the middle name.. But your problem would be the proper delimiter. What if the name is "Damascus, Joseph S A" with the middle name "S A" with a space? What if it was "S. A."?

I suggest redesigning the tables to accomodate Firstname, middlename, lastname (even nickname, title, suffix) or setting rules in your application that avoids spaces with middle initials.

Comment: Well the table comes from an Excel we get on a monthly basis. I import the file to create the table. I could manipulate it before the import, but I need to make it simple enough for someone else to use. I am trying to make a tool to put it in the format I need to import into my CRM

Comment: Well, is it possible for users to submit to you a file with distinct columns for what you need?

Comment: Also, don't forget to upvote answers that have helped. Just a friendly SO reminder :)

Comment: I cant change the table design since the data comes from a vendor in an Excel file. I ended up using a sub-query to get what I needed. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Will there always be a comma separating Last from other parts? What if there is no middle initial? This is why name parts should be stored in separate fields.

Maybe:

x represents your field.

FirstName = Left(Mid(x, InStr(x,",") + 2), InStr(Mid(x, InStr(x,",") + 2), " "))

Comment: Yes the comma will always be there. I will give this a try. Thank you!

Comment: I think I will have to use several Iif statements to cover my bases

Comment: Problem with IIf() is that both expressions (the true and false calcs) must be able to be calculated, otherwise the function will error. However, Switch() might work.